# CORS AWS S3 and cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I see different headers returned from the server using curl and browsers(FF and Chrome).

Curl returns CORS headers

```
curl -X GET -I -H "Origin: https://qa.gameofshred.com"  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/gameofshred-qa/site/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749.svg --verbose

> GET /gameofshred-qa/site/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749.svg HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
> Accept: */*
> Origin: https://qa.gameofshred.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: m9oDqyGs0K+0IBnygQlGE9IEeVZQcpIf1nYSWYYu5NU5Hu3gNEUy8SfWnO/mFiK8nPIBPlDhWec=
x-amz-id-2: m9oDqyGs0K+0IBnygQlGE9IEeVZQcpIf1nYSWYYu5NU5Hu3gNEUy8SfWnO/mFiK8nPIBPlDhWec=
< x-amz-request-id: 135C9D56C2C0D604
x-amz-request-id: 135C9D56C2C0D604
< Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 02:37:34 GMT
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 02:37:34 GMT
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
< Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
< Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Apr 2017 23:02:06 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Apr 2017 23:02:06 GMT
< ETag: "912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde"
ETag: "912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
< Content-Length: 444379
Content-Length: 444379
< Server: AmazonS3
Server: AmazonS3
```

Browsers on the other hand don't contain any CORS headers.

Request:

```
GET /gameofshred-qa/site/fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749.svg HTTP/1.1
Host: s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
Origin: https://qa.gameofshred.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges → bytes
Content-Length → 444379
Content-Type → image/svg+xml
Date → Wed, 19 Apr 2017 02:32:37 GMT
ETag → "912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde"
Last-Modified → Tue, 18 Apr 2017 23:02:06 GMT
Server → AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2 → O0V/q2q9vSKQgJWKUL8LfsQghKlyBS90fTYDt9TLcgJimjeCUKg57+UwgAnWym8tJRPpGsRutG0=
x-amz-request-id → 5EA7299EC61D0E86
```

Any explanation? Thanks.

UPD:
As was suggested I updated cors configuration. It didn't help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>55</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

UPD 2:
The problem apparently was caused by two reasons
1) CDN caching
2) Using Postman for checking CORS. Postman(browser version) always substitutes ORIGIN to something like "chrome://extensions...." so we cannot use it for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding: `<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>` to CORS configuration in AWS S3:

Bucket > Permissions > CORS configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Then you should see in browsers & curl:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
```

Comment: It doesn't help... still the same

Comment: @ArtemIbragimov When I edited the CORS configuration in AWS it took a little time before seeing the correct headers. Don't know if it is your case but it never hurts to wait.

Comment: That's why I updated MaxAgeSeconds, so I could know for sure when  the changes took place.. I see updated "Access-Control-Max-Age" in curl but the browser is still the same

Comment: @ArtemIbragimov I entered your site, and I'm seeing the correct headers from fonts served from cloudfront. Can you point me to an URL where you're serving the svg from your example, since I'm not seeing it in the homepage. At least Roboto-Medium.ttf has he right headers.

Comment: you are right...  I just tried to enter the website from USA and it worked...  But on my local machine it doesn't though I try to access by 1) Private Window(so there is no cache used) 2) By Postman So weird...

Comment: I think cloudfront cached it with old headers in my region and keeps it this way until it expires.

Comment: @ArtemIbragimov the headers in the original question show no evidence that you are actually using CloudFront.  The `X-Amz-Cf-Id`, `Via`, and `X-Cache` headers provided by CloudFront are all missing.  You are accessing the bucket, directly.  To use CloudFront, you have to actually route the request to CloudFront, not to the bucket URL.